# Data storage dilemma - As an integer count or as an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, design-patterns, storage

This one should be pretty easy for an experienced programmer to answer.

I've got a Rails App where users are encouraged to click different buttons that are featured all around the site. When it comes to storing the data, I need to record two things:

1) The total number of people that have clicked each individual button.
2) The number of unique people that have clicked each individual button.

95% percent of the time, I don't need to know WHO the people that actually did the clicking are. This data is accessed very frequently. The other 5% of the time I DO need to know who clicked what, and I need to iterate over those people and perform certain actions.

Right now I have a Click model that records the user and the button for each click. What I'm not sure about is whether I should be doing some sort of unique select on the clicks to find the unique ones, or if I should create a separate model for unique clicks. Furthermore, would it be smart to create a num_clicks column for the button model and increment it each time someone clicks as well as adding the click as a record? Or should I just do a select count(*) each time?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Definitely use `num_clicks` attribute for this problem. It solves getting unique clicks and total clicks together. This way, you can just keep one model Click as well. You'd have to make sure though the uniqueness of user-button data when it is saved in Click table.

Comment: Are you talking about adding the counter column as part of the button model, or as part of the click model?

Comment: Yes. That's what I would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the counter cache columns for all your purposes.

Comment: Did not know about counter cache. Looks to be very helpful. Gonna give it a go...